# Edit php files on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new on Amazon web service, Actually, I create a new application on aws server and upload my website all files, and also set up the database. Aws provide me a link where I can check my website, now all things are working fine.
My problem is that when I am going to edit any single file, I am not able to edit it only zip file I can see on aws.

if i want to change some code then I need to upload whole zip again then changes will be done. I search about this many times but did not get any solutions.

Can anyone help me how I can edit and update any files on aws? Thanks

Comment: You can try to copy it by ssh and restart the web server.

Comment: You can make changes to the particular file by ssh to the EC2 instance, but these changes are temporary. If your instance gets replaced by a new one due to Autoscaling or application rebuild action then the changes made by you are get vanished. For permanent changes, you need to upload a complete ZIP file.

Answer (score 1):

While it may not seem so, this should be actually an advantage. If you edit the code on the instance and then the instance would fail, what would you do? What if you make a mistake and your public site went offline? Do you do some testing before you publish your code?

The big idea behind CI/CD/DevOps is that you have a setup which would do it for you automatically. For example you can use CodeCommit as your source repository and then build an pipeline which will deliver the changes to the instance automatically. Here is a first step tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/deploy-codecommit-elastic-beanstalk/

It may look very complex, but once you will have a working delivery pipeline I think you will not want to go back.

Comment: HI thanks for your solution, I Just check your comment. I am successfully connected the ftp through key pair with public key and private key. and i am able to make changes in all files. can you please tell me this is good way to edit and update files  or not?

Comment: If the instance fails (e.g. it can be automatically removed by AWS because of failed hardware), what is your plan for recovery? From the devops standpoint what you should try to achieve is to have a setup which in case of the failure of the instance will replace it automatically without you even knowing it including your changes. FTP may work for development, but is not really the idea behind beanstalk or similar services. Let you check CodeDeploy, you may use a different service, but CodeDeploy may help you to see the possibilities.

Comment: Still, I am using the free tier version. I don't know about failer option of aws hardware. I am new here so just checked videos and upload my website on aws.